# Erro de implementação

Tags: php, laravel

Estou chamando a classe `TenantScope` na model `Cliente` e dá erro

TenantScope.php

```
namespace App\Scopes\Tenant;

use App\Tenant\ManagerTenant;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

class TenantScope implements Scope

{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {


        $tenant = new ManagerTenant;
        $tenant->getTenantIdentify();

        $builder->where('tenant_id', $tenant)->get();
    }
}
```

Erro:

```
Whoops\Exception\ErrorException  : Declaration of App\Scopes\Tenant\TenantScope::apply(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $builder, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model) must be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope::apply(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model)
```

Cliente.php  //Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use app\Scopes\Tenant\TenantScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cliente extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome',
     ];

    ´    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new TenantScope);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a própria exception, o protótipo da sua função `apply` está aceitando um parâmetro do tipo `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`, quando deveria aceitar um do tipo `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.

No caso, bastaria corrigir a importação da classe Builder:

TenantScope.php

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder; // antes
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder; // depois
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado